# Concatenate 2 dataframe in alternate way ( first column of first dataframe, first column of second dataframe and so on but with column names unchanged

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind, r-colnames

Hello i am new to R programming and i am stuck with one problem. I would like to combine 2 dataframe into a new one in this way. First column of first dataframe, first column of second dataframe and then the third column of the new dataframe should be the difference between the 2 columns before, and iterate the process for all the columns of the dataframe ( they have same size of course). The crucial point is that the new columns should have their name unchanged.... this is where i get stuck. Please help meeee

i tried to iterate a for loop and combine through cbind but then i don't know how to leave the column names unchanged

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What should the difference column be named? What code are you using that changes the column names?

Comment: The output you're describing, with 3x the columns, seems like something that will be human readable but a pain to do any further analysis with. If you intend to do more calculations with it, I suggest reshaping the data "long" before you do any more steps.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code

```
cbind(data1, data2, data3)[order(rep(seq(data1), 3))]
```

---

Explanation:

You said you have two datasets `data1` and `data2`, and a 3rd dataset which is the difference of the two datasets. Here is a quick way to go about it

```
data1 <- head(iris[1:3])
data2 <- head(trees)
data3 <- data1 - data2
names(data3) <- paste0(names(data1), '_', names(data2))
```

---

Having the data above, to get the desired output we could simply do:

```
cbind(data1, data2, data3)[order(rep(seq(data1), 3))]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cbind the data.frames you will get the original column names which I think was your goal. You can then rearrange the columns with a trick that depends on how R matrices behave when "unfolded" with the `c()` function:

```
t( matrix(1:6,,2) )  # could also use matrix(1:6, 2, byrow=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    4    5    6
> c( t( matrix(1:6,,2) ) ) # third arg to `matrix` is "ncol"
[1] 1 4 2 5 3 6
```

So make such a matrix that depends on twice the length of the dataframes and then use it to reorder the result of cbind()-ing:

```
    df_both <- cbind(dat1, dat2)[ c( t( matrix(1:(2*length(dat1), ,2) ) )
```